# An IDE in my pocket?

Tags: android, ide, ios

Does anyone know of an IDE for editing files such as PHP, HTML, and CSS through a SFTP connection? I  have both an android device and an iOS (version  3, that is) device, and the only result I get for an application like this in both marketplaces is in the App Store. It didn't seem particularly appealing (also, it required an iOS 4 upgrade), and i'd prefer something for my android device (it has a hardware keyboard). Is there such a thing out there?

Thanks.

Comment: SFTP is for securely transferring files. Do you mean tunneling through SSH?

Comment: @AphexMunky actually, no - I mean editing files through SFTP by grabbing the file from  the server, editing it on the device, then transferring the edited file back to the server. I just want SFTP integrated into the editor.

Comment: @benvd I've tried ConnectBot + nano, but it was somewhat problematic, not to mention frustrating. Lag was  an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is pretty old now, but just in case for anyone else.  Two AndExplorer and AndFTP Pro.  You can mount a virtual SFTP site as a directory and then use whatever.  Use it on my Droid X quite a bit.